# 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.' Error occurred when converting from JSON in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am now working to convert datetime object in multi-objects JSON array to insert into a table SQL server. The problem is the datetime object contains timezone sign `'+'` or `'-'` and `'T'` for time as follow:

```
"2018-05-04T10:31:31.134+06:30"
```

I would like to insert directly the above value to `DATETIME` object in a table from SQL Server. At that time, the **ERROR** is

> 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.'

I already tried with the following way.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"EntryDateTime":"2018-05-04T10:31:31.134+06:30"}';
DECLARE @tmp AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @tmp= CONVERT(datetime2(3), JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.EntryDateTime'))
SET @json = JSON_MODIFY(@json, '$.EntryDateTime', @tmp)

print @json
```

But it works only for one JSON object. I would like to convert datetimeoffset format of multi-object JSON array to datetime like

```
'[{"EntryDateTime":"2018-05-04T10:31:31.134+06:30"},{"EntryDateTime":"2018-05-05T09:13:00.134+06:30"}]'
```

Comment: But that's not a `Datetime`, that's a `DatetimeOffset`...

Comment: I have DATETIME type in my Table, Is there anyway to convert all datatimeoffset values in json array to datatime?

Comment: `datetimeoffset` preserves the timezone. `datetime` does not. You first need to pick the timezone (UTC?) that you want to save the data in.

Comment: Are you seeking for a single command that would change the datetime format for all instances of your JSON array?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid , I do not want UTC. I want datetime only.

Comment: @FDavidov Yes! I need that one

Comment: So, not even a loop? Well, I wish you good luck!!!

Comment: @FDavidov, I already throught about it. But I want to know about another way instead of using loop. Anyway, Thank you.

Comment: If you're not interested in the timezone that the datetime was recorded in (the +06:30 piece), just use the `LEFT` function to remove it.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Do I need to use 'LEFT' function for all objects using loop? I want a single command to remove all UTC parts.

Comment: 1. Use `OPENJSON` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/convert-json-data-to-rows-and-columns-with-openjson-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017 to convert your serialised JSON into a virtual table; 2. Use your existing `CONVERT` to convert each row as required.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! @Nick.McDermaid